# Buttons in my App are different sizes on different phones

Tags: android

I am developing an Android App.

I have a few Android Devices and in my Emulator the App looked just how i wanted it. I tested it out on my MyTouch and looked perfect as well. But when i test the App out on my LG Ally the buttons are significantly smaller!

Is there a way to fix this?

The App is called PostSecret on the Android Market. You can download it and see what the buttons do on your phone if you want...

I cant post any images yet because of my rank on this site :( But the logo has a black background with a silver border and *PS* written inside of the logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyTouch is having a 320 x 480 pixels screen and a medium density, where else LG Ally is 480 x 800 pixels and high density.

You have to understand the concept of [density](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

> A screen with lower density has fewer
>   available pixels spread across the
>   screen width and height, where a
>   screen with higher density has more —
>   sometimes significantly more — pixels
>   spread across the same area. The
>   density of a screen is important
>   because, other things being equal, a
>   **UI element (such as a button) whose
>   height and width are defined in terms
>   of screen pixels will appear larger on
>   the lower density screen and smaller
>   on the higher density screen**.

One way is to define your buttons in density independant pixels(dp) instead of px.

E.g. `android:layout_width="40dp"` `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Your buttons are scaled in pixels, while the device resolution varies. Try using % or a similar unit, or make the dimensions of each button relative to the width and height of the screen.